# Cordova iOS platform v4 - shouldstartloadwithrequest not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I have updated an old app made with Cordova 1.8. They customized a lot of code from the generated classes, so I tried my best to update everything.

However, there's now something I just don't get now even when the base code is practically the same; the `shouldstartloadwithrequest` that is in my "MainViewController.m" file is not being called, instead it calls the one in "CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m" from the Cordova framework.

I have read that I needed to add `webView.delegate = self;` in the `viewDidLoad` method, but it's not working (I previously added the property in the h file, and synthesized it).

I don't want to edit the Cordova framework files.

Is there a way in the new iOS platform to make the same thing that was possible in the old one (i.e make my own `shouldstartloadwithrequest` in the generated file "MainViewController.m" work)?

Comment: Were you able to achieve it? I had to do the samething as well.